# ember simple auth authenticate callback issue

Tags: javascript, authentication, ember.js, ember-simple-auth

I am using ember simple auth to make a custom auth system using ember, everything works fine expect one issue, can't pass data from authenticate promise callback to login controller.

code below:

```
  //the login goes here
  authenticate: function(options) {
    return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      Ember.$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: apis.login,
        data: JSON.stringify({
          username: options.identification,
          password: options.password
        })
      }).then(function(response) {
        // check the login status to check the status
        if (response.status === "success") {
          //pass the response in resolve callback
          Ember.run(function() {
            resolve(response);
          });
        } else {
          //login failed, pass the response in reject callback
          Ember.run(function() {
            reject(response);
          });
        }
      }, function(xhr, status, error) {
        Ember.run(function() {
          reject(xhr.responseJSON || xhr.responseText);
        });
      });
    });
  },
```

and the controller code here

```
  actions: {
    // display an error when authentication fails
    authenticate: function() {
      var _this = this;
      var credentials = this.getProperties('identification', 'password');
      this.get('session').authenticate('authenticator:custom', credentials).then(
      function(message) {
        //the issus happens here, the message here is undefined
        console.log(message);
        _this.get('session').set('username', message.username);
      }, function(message) {
        // but the reject callback works fine, the message is the right one
        console.log(message);
        _this.set('errorMessage', message.msg);
        _this.set('identification', '');
        _this.set('password', '');
      });
    }
  }
```

could someone help me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The session's `authenticate` resolves with no value as @damienc points out. However, you can access everything the authenticator resolves with via the session's `secure` property, e.g. `this.get('session.secure.token')`. So you can simply change your code to

```
actions: {
  authenticate: function() {
    var _this = this;
    var credentials = this.getProperties('identification', 'password');
    this.get('session').authenticate('authenticator:custom', credentials).then(
    function() {
      //the issus happens here, the message here is undefined
      console.log(_this.get('session.secure.whatever'));
      _this.get('session').set('username', message.username);
    }, function(error) {
      // but the reject callback works fine, the message is the right one
      console.log(error);
      _this.set('errorMessage', error.msg);
      _this.set('identification', '');
      _this.set('password', '');
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Session` delegates the authentication to the `Authenticator` (`authenticate`, `restore`…) but will always resolve returning no value.

This means that in your `Controller` example, the resolved promise will never have any parameter.

```
this.get('session')
  .authenticate('authenticator:custom', credentials)
  .then(function(/* there are parameters here, see session implementation */) {
    _this.get('session').set('username', message.username);
  }, function(message) {
    /* */
  });
```

This is clear inspecting `Session` source code  here: https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth/blob/master/packages/ember-simple-auth/lib/simple-auth/session.js#L158

You could use a custom `Session` object and override the `authenticate` method to have it return the value you need.